# Getting individual Directory Names in a Path Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, path, pathlib

Say i have a path like this

Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/

Doesn't necessarily have to have the final slash.
How do i extract just "Folder2".

Comment: Splitting by '/' separator and get the index of list  that you need `'Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/'.split('/')[1]`

Comment: I saw this, was just looking for a specific os.path function to do it. Many thanks though!

Comment: What O.S. are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 'pathlib' module of the standard library:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> pathlib.PurePath('Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/').parts[1]
```

you get:

> 'Folder2'

Or for subdirs paths:

```
>>> pathlib.PurePath('Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/').parents[1]
```

You get:

> PurePosixPath('Folder1/Folder2')